# hMailServer Email + MX Records Configuration

Tags: mx-record, hmailserver

Trying to make DNS changes to enable email to be sent using hMailServer.

My mail server is on a separate machine with a separate IP Address.

I have already added MyDomain.com and an email account

I have create a MX Record with the mail server being mail.domain.com an a priority on 20.

1) But the question is how do I now link this MX record for the domain to my mail server/ mail server IP Address?

2) What changes are needed in hMailServer to complete the process and be able to send emails for the domain?

3) In Settings > SMTP > Delivery of email: What should my configuration here look like?

Comment: I've also added the host as mail.Domain.com and added an A Record for mail.Domain.com to the mail server IP Address

Comment: Tracked the problem down to this: No reverse DNS (PTR) entries. The problem MX records are: 
181.226.129.78.in-addr.arpa -> no reverse (PTR) detected

What/How do I add a Reverse PTR?

Comment: Take a look at mxtoolbox.com - it will diagnostics and point you in the right direction.

Comment: Well all I had to do was add in a RDNS which is basically just a PTR.
After that I had to disable Clamwin antivirus from scanning emails. Everything worked perfect after that.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your second comment that you've tracked it down to reverse PTRs, then you need to have your reverse zone have the matching pointers for MX records. If you don't run your own reverse DNS then you'd have to ask the entity who does (the people upstream from you owning the netblock) to add these entries for you.

```
<last .quad of IP>  IN   PTR  machine.domain.com.
```

This goes in the reverse zone file as mentioned, not your forward zone. A quick whois based on your comment of 78.129.226.181 shows it's Rapidswitch owned, so I'm going to guess they do your reverse for you and you only get a few IPs of a hosted server to play with - open a support ticket.